# How to sort an array in PHP using my own predefined rules?

Tags: php

I am supposed to sort a given array using the following rules:

The sort will need to be case insensitive and place all the characters in alphabetical order first, then numbers, and finally all the other characters, each in the 3 groups following the ASCII order.

I tried "sort" and "natcasesort" functions, but the result is not what I was expecting.
I am supposed to execute my code like this:

> ./ssap2.php toto tutu 4234 "_hop A2l+ XXX" ## "1948372 AhAhAh"

(sorry for the bad code, this is my first day on PHP :) )

```
/* function to split the given arguments */

function    ft_split($string)
{
    $arr = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $string);
    return $arr;
}

$brut = array();
$alpha = array();
$numeric = array();
$other = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < $argc; $i++)
{
    $brut = array_merge($brut, ft_split($argv[$i]));
}

foreach ($brut as $elem)
{
    if (is_numeric($elem))
        $numeric[] = $elem;
    else if (ctype_alpha($elem))
        $alpha[] = $elem;
    else
        $other[] = $elem;
}
sort($numeric);
natcasesort($alpha);
sort($other);

foreach ($alpha as $word)
    echo $word."\n";
foreach ($numeric as $word)
    echo $word."\n";
foreach ($other as $word)
    echo $word."\n";
?>
```

I expect something like this:

$> ./ssap2.php toto tutu 4234 "_hop A2l+ XXX" ## "1948372 AhAhAh"

AhAhAh

A2l+

toto

tutu

XXX

1948372

4234

## #

_hop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this function :

```
function ft_compare($s1, $s2)
{
    $map = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 !\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~";
    $s1 = strtolower($s1);
    $s2 = strtolower($s2);
    $len1 = strlen($s1);
    $len2 = strlen($s2);
    while ($i < $len1)
    {
        if ($i >= $len2)
            return 1;
        $pos1 = strpos($map, $s1[$i]);
        $pos2 = strpos($map, $s2[$i]);
        if ($pos1 < $pos2)
            return -1;
        else if ($pos1 > $pos2)
            return 1;
        $i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

combined with "usort"